# key words are not displayed in app store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, keyword

My application is in three languages - Russian, Italian and Portuguese. I added key words for all of these languages (main one is Russian), but in app store you can only find the app by Russian key words, not the other two. Could you, please, help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `App store` is divided by countries or regions. And your device is probably in Russian `App store`. If you whant to check your application in another regions you can change your device region (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389)

Comment: The problem did not go away even when I changed the region. Also, this application is available for all the countries.